# Command + Tab not working as intended

Tags: macos, shortcut, mojave

I am having problems switching between applications using <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> on my MacBook Pro (macOS Mojave). Every now and then when I use <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> and release the buttons when a desired application is highlighted, the system goes to the Finder view instead of the Application.

This happens despite the fact that the applications are all maximized and should have their own view. I have tried Googling this problem without any luck.

Comment: When you say it goes to the Finder "view", do you mean to a view of the desktop or it just invokes Finder while leaving the last app you were on still visible?

Comment: It goes to a view of the desktop.

Comment: Try booting into Safe Mode (hold shift while booting) and see if the problem persists.  This will give you a "clean" macOS environment to rule out app compatibility issues.  If the problem persists, it might be an issue with macOS itself.